# NLog for Windows Phone 7/8

Tags: windows-phone-7, logging, windows-phone-8, nlog

I'm looking for a way to easy logging in Windows Phone application, Nlog is what I'm trying to get it to work but don't know how to. I couldn't find a guide for Windows Phone. If anyone know how to setup NLog or any other tool, library that help working with logging please suggest

Thanks  you.

Comment: NLog has a tutorial for this: http://nlog-project.org/2011/01/09/nlog-for-windows-phone-7.html

Comment: I follow the step and install the NLog, but when I open visual studio, I don't see the NLog template thing... I use visual studio 2012 Professional

Answer (score 0):

[Follow the tutorial](http://nlog-project.org/2011/01/09/nlog-for-windows-phone-7.html) and make sure you use the manual method for the last two steps:

- If you prefer, you manually add reference to "C:\Program Files (x86)\NLog\Silverlight for Windows Phone 7\NLog.dll" instead and create NLog.config manually
- One last thing is changing Build Action for NLog.config to ‘Content’ (this ensures that the file will be included in the XAP package).